# How to bind component name in angular component's template?

Tags: angular

What I want is something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: "test",
    template: `<{{componentName}}></{{componentName}}>`,
})
export class NodeComponent {
    @Input()
    componentName: string; // the html tag name or custom component name or custom component class
}
```

I know the above code doesn't work, if it works:

```
<test componentName="button"></test>
```

will be rendered as:

```
<button></button>
```

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? It would help with finding a good solution.

Comment: @JánHalaša For example, I want to create a list component, it has some behaviours that is not related to its items, so if I create a item component as the list component's input property, the list component can be used with all kinds of items.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand it. Maybe if you edit your question and add one or two examples of what you want to achieve.